# How to select all records where related collection is empty with Mongoid

Tags: mongodb, associations, counting, mongoid3

I'm still getting the hang of MongoDB and Mongoid and have hit this snag.

Let's say I have a `User` that `has_and_belongs_to_many` `items` and of course an `Item` that `has_and_belongs_to_many` `users`.

I'd like to be able to count the Users with any Items.

[this question](/questions/12098507/mongoid-how-to-select-objects-with-empty-associations) recommended adding a `scope` so I tried adding a scope to `User` such as

```
scope :has_no_items, where(:items.empty?)
```

but `User.count - User.has_no_items.count` returns `0`.

I've looked at `.with_size` but that's specific to Array fields.

What is the correct way to do this other than

```
count = 0
User.each { |u| count += 1 unless u.items.empty? }
```

which works but it doesn't seem very elegant.

How do I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me with Rails 3.2.13, Mongoid 3.1.4, Moped 1.5.0.

app/models/user.rb

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
  scope :has_items, where(:item_ids.ne => nil)
  scope :has_no_items, where(:item_ids => nil)
end
```

app/models/item.rb

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

test/unit/user_test.rb

require 'test_helper'

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    User.delete_all
    Item.delete_all
  end

  test "users without items" do
    fagin = User.create(:name => 'Fagin')
    oliver = User.create(:name => 'Oliver')
    fagin.items << Item.create(:name => 'cane')
    assert_equal 2, User.count
    assert_equal 1, Item.count
    assert_equal 1, User.has_items.count
    assert_equal 1, User.has_no_items.count
    puts
    puts "User.has_items: #{User.has_items.to_a.inspect}"
    puts "User.has_no_items: #{User.has_no_items.to_a.inspect}"
  end
end
```

rake test

```
Run options:

# Running tests:

[1/1] UserTest#test_users_without_items
User.has_items: [#<User _id: 51df00987f11ba3d7d000001, name: "Fagin", item_ids: ["51df00987f11ba3d7d000003"]>]
User.has_no_items: [#<User _id: 51df00987f11ba3d7d000002, name: "Oliver", item_ids: nil>]
Finished tests in 0.042205s, 23.6939 tests/s, 94.7755 assertions/s.
1 tests, 4 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Hope that this helps.